# Externalize the files under src/main/resources not only application.properties but also other folders present in it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm having a requirement that we are developing a application that requires some files like txt, json etc., currently these files are present inside the **src/main/resources** folder but we are distributing this app as **jar file**. So we need to externalize these files present inside resources folder like we used to externalize application.properties file outside the jar

Is there any way to externalize the files along with the application.properties. I had tried put these files local to the jar file but spring is not overriding the files, any help is appreciated

Comment: *So we need to externalize these files* unless any needs to be written to, they should be in your jar as resources

Comment: What do you mean by "spring is not overriding the files"? Can you explain what you are doing at app startup and what you are seeing?

Comment: Hi @EricGeorge, thanks for your reply, actually when we put our properties file outside the jar, Spring will use it as priority right? rather than the property file present inside the jar, that same behaviour I want to achieve with the other files (txt, json, xml, etc., ) as well. Like how to tell to the spring that to consider files present outside the jar rather than inside ones.

Comment: I was trying to ask, are you starting it from the command line like `java -jar myjar.jar`? Or running in a docker container? Or from an IDE? Or with gradle or maven?

Comment: Also, can you post the code that utilizes the files in the resource folder?

Comment: How are the other files (txt, json, xml, etc) used? Spring Boot has logic to locate and use application.properties and application.yml files. If your application is opening and reading the txt, json, xml, etc files directly then it is up to your application to locate the files. Spring's `Resource` abstraction can be useful for this purpose: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#resources.